# Capitalized "Edit" and "Delete" buttons for comments are inconsistent with other UI elements

Tags: bug, comments, design, capitalization

> [image]

Just recently the `Edit` and `Delete` buttons for comments went capitalized, while most other buttons (links) remain completely lowercase. This creates an inconsistency in UI.

Can we either get back `edit` and `delete`, or update `share`, `edit` etc. into `Share`, `Edit` etc. sooner?

Comment: `$('head').append("<style>.comment-edit, .comment-delete { text-transform: lowercase; }</style>")` works

Comment: I'd rather the post links be updated with capitalization. ;) Capitalized words are becoming the new standard UI here, so I kind of doubt this will be changed back.

Comment: Looks like Share/Edit/Close/Flag now have capitalisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Per [@Wai Ha Lee's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323295/capitalized-edit-and-delete-buttons-for-comments-are-inconsistent-with-other?noredirect=1#comment1199846_323295), we now have properly capitalized post action links:

> [image]

Comment: But now the "add a comment" and "start a bounty" prompts are inconsistent...

Comment: @F1Krazy As well as the "show N more comments" clickable link.