# Unable to follow while in Review Queue

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review, follow-post

While reviewing some Late Answers and First Posts noticed that it's not possible to click "follow" and start following the post.

[image: can't follow while in review queue]

In order to do it at the moment, I had to go to the page where the answer resides outside of the Review queue.

[image: following out it the Review Queue]

This behaviour was first noticed in Stack Overflow but I was able to reproduce it in other sites like Project Management Stack Exchange.

Comment: Reproduced on skeptics

Comment: July 21, 2020: The current behavior seems to be that clicking follow will run the appropriate functions so that you will be following the post. The popup notices will trigger, but not always if you try toggling by clicking the link multiple times. As for user experience, the link text does not change, so you have no confidence that it worked.

Comment: July 26, 2020 - In moderator review on mobile Chrome the follow link did not work at all. Both "you are following" and "you are no longer following" popups came up in sequence and the post was not added to my followed list.

Comment: Reproduced on [SO.ja](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3394)

Comment: Reproduced on lots of other SEs; world-building, SF&F, RPG, ELL, etc.; it’s probably network-wide.

Comment: Reproduced on [ubuntu.se] https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19317/1103140

Comment: Exact thing happened yesterday as "July 26, 2020" comment above, but I see they're working on it, so thank you.

Comment: Reproduced on Physics.SE

Comment: Since the day this was reported, only now felt the need to do it again (follow while in Review) and couldn't. The reason for wanting to do it was to keep notified about an answer i think to be very low quality in a community I'm still relatively new to. The notifications would help me understand how other more experienced users deal with it.

Comment: I just got one concern with this feature... If one is reviewing posts would a click in "follow" be enough to count as valid review?

Comment: same on U&L (tested on mobile, Chrome), unable to follow from the review queue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work now after [today's update to the post menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323295/295232):

[image]

<sub>(this answer previously contained a userscript to fix this bug)</sub>

Comment: Fwiw, this is included in the work on redoing the review task ui that is underway right now

Comment: @YaakovEllis even better, it has been fixed with today's update to the post menu...

Comment: You're both winners.  It was fixed with the post menu update which is part of the review queue project, but also it was explicitly fixed ahead of time as part of the same project because the changes made it trivial to add the one-line fix to the existing review queue code.