# Cite does not work from review

Tags: bug, review, citation

Just like [following a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350648/295232), citing a post (on sites with the [citation](/questions/tagged/citation) feature enabled) from the First Posts and Late Answers queue doesn't work.

[image]

(I'm not sure if citing is really useful from the review queue, so removing the link altogether is probably a good solution as well, and perhaps easier to implement.)

This issue affects most of the scientific sites in the network (e.g. Mathematics, Physics), that's why I'm posting it here. My original bug report was [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483/228959) on Mathematics Meta.