# Tooltips with different styles after a fix was done

Tags: feature-request, design, tooltips

This was found in Windows 10 with Chrome.

After the resolution of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350648/364217), I noticed that we have the following tooltip style when hovering on "Following"

[image]

When we hover in the others, for instance in "Share"

[image]

the styles don't match. Personally I like the new one more.

Note that one doesn't need to be in Review Queues to see this style difference.

Comment: First reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396760)